# Updating graph as I drag a point around

Tags: d3.js

I am making a line of best fit app using d3 in which I want the line of best fit to update as I drag the points around. I got it work so that when your drag ends, the line updates by itself. However, when it comes to actually updating as the point is being dragged, I am unable to do so.

Here is my drag function:

```
 var move =  d3.behavior.drag()
                .on("drag",drag)
                .on("dragend",function(){
                    dict.length = 0;
                    var dragPoint = d3.select(this);
                    var newX = x_scale2(parseInt(dragPoint.attr("cx")));
                    var newY = y_scale2(parseInt(dragPoint.attr("cy")));

                    model.replace_point(dragPoint.attr("id"),newX,newY);
                    updateDisplay();


            });

  function drag(){
      var dragPoint = d3.select(this);
      dragPoint
    .attr("cx",function(){return d3.event.dx + parseInt(dragPoint.attr("cx"));})
    .attr("cy",function(){return d3.event.dy +parseInt(dragPoint.attr("cy"));})
        }
```

** Any help on how to accomplish my goal would be appreciated **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just include you 'update-code' in the drag function.
The line will then be update every time the drag event is fired. Which means every time the position of the point changes.

```
var move = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on("drag", drag);

function drag() {
    var dragPoint = d3.select(this);
    dragPoint
        .attr("cx", d3.event.dx + parseInt(dragPoint.attr("cx")))
        .attr("cy", d3.event.dy + parseInt(dragPoint.attr("cy")));
    var newX = x_scale2(parseInt(dragPoint.attr("cx")));
    var newY = y_scale2(parseInt(dragPoint.attr("cy")));
    model.replace_point(dragPoint.attr("id"), newX, newY);
    updateDisplay();
}
```